# Meteor collection update throws exception

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My code:

```
    try {
        Alerts.update({_id: alertId}, {
            $set: {
                number_of_new_results: 0,
                number_of_stored_results: 0,
                last_time_run: null
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

It generates the exception:

```
W20160421-16:17:37.739(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\xauxatz\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.4.42\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
W20160421-16:17:37.739(2)? (STDERR)         throw message;      
W20160421-16:17:37.740(2)? (STDERR)               ^
W20160421-16:17:37.740(2)? (STDERR) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I have absolutely no idea what's causing the problem. This particular update works other places in the code.

Edit:
The above code is running on the server, within:

```
if( Meteor.isServer ) {

    Meteor.methods({

.....................

    });

}
```

Comment: Look like you are making a wrong call. Basically its happen when your container full due to any reason.

Comment: Where does that code come from? Some information on its context would be useful.

Comment: Are you running this in a helper by any chance?

Comment: Sorry - I added a bit of context above. So it is unfortunately not running within a helper. It is called with Meteor.call from a helper. What does it mean that the container is full, Pankaj Jatav?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself (as so often happens). The error resulted from a recursive call. The above code was called when a certain alert was updated. And the code within the function caused the alert to be updated again :-(